# SQLite query for comparing database value and system time

Tags: android, database, sqlite, time

I want to compare the value which i already stored in database with current system value.
and pls give answer for following question

SQLite query for comparing database value and system time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be an expression, not a query: `julianday() < mydate` evaluates to true if `mydate` falls after the current date and time. `mydate` must be the number of days (with fractional hours) since a particular moment in time in 4714 B.C.

The details are all [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), including explanations of how to get dates into and out of different representations, including the Unix epoch.